# Use loop to bind events

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
//I hava this tool function to bind event
var bindEvent = function($dom,events,data,_this){
  for(var key in events){
    $dom.bind(key,function(){
      events[key].apply(_this,[data]);
    });
  }
};

//and use like this
var events = {
  click:function(){
    alert("click");
  },
  dblclick:function(){
    alert("dblclick");
  }
};

var $btn = $("#btn");
bindEvent($btn,events,"mydata",$btn);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">MYBtn</button>
```

when i click on the button, dblclick event is always being triggered.
I know, the reason of this problem.
There is a closure when bind event which is used in "for" loop. Upon termination of loop, the last object in memory (there is dbclick callback function).
so, when trigger `click` event, it run `alert("dblclick")`.
I want to know if had a good way to solve this problem.
Or have a good way to implement tool function for bind event.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `closure` inside `for-in` loop(while attaching `event`) where `inner-function` will remember the environment in which it is created!

```js
var bindEvent = function($dom, events, data, _this) {
  for (var key in events) {
    $dom.bind(key, (function(key) {
      return function() {
        events[key].apply(_this, [data]);
      }
    })(key));
  }
};
var events = {
  click: function() {
    console.log("click");
  },
  dblclick: function() {
    console.log("dblclick");
  }
};

var $btn = $("#btn");
bindEvent($btn, events, "mydata", $btn);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">MYBtn</button>
```

**Note:** As `alert` is being invoked on `click` event, `dblclick` event is prevented, use `console.log` instead of `alert` and test!

Comment: when do double click it also trigger clicks two time.

Comment: @HareshVidja – What do one mean by [__Double__](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=double+meaning&oq=double+me&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.4903j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) ? If you are clicking twice, won't it invoke the handler twice ?

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: @YingYi — I'm glad it helped mate! _Happy Coding_

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you would need `data`, but in general you don't need a loop for adding more than one event. You can just pass the object to `bind` or `on`. And because in an event `this` is always the element, you don't need to set the context.

```js
$("#btn").on({
    click: function() {
        console.log("click");
    },
    dblclick: function() {
        console.log("dblclick");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">MYBtn</button>
```

Or as *long version* with your wrapper function:

```js
var bindEvent = function($dom, events) {
    $dom.bind(events);
};

var events = {
    click: function(){
        console.log("click");
    },
    dblclick: function(){
        console.log("dblclick");
    }
};

var $btn = $("#btn");
bindEvent($btn, events);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">MYBtn</button>
```

Comment: I had up-vote the answer.I need to use `apply`, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Both event always contradict but you can achiev this by counter number of clicks between small time interval.

```js
//I hava this tool function to bind event
var bindEvent = function($dom,events,data,_this){
    $dom.on(events);
  
};
var dblckickinterval = 500, clicks = 0, timer = null;
//and use like this
var events = {
  click:function(e){
   clicks++;  //count clicks

        if(clicks === 1) {
            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                alert("click");  //perform single-click action    
                clicks = 0; //after action performed, reset counter
            }, dblckickinterval);
        } else {

            clearTimeout(timer);    //prevent single-click action
            alert("dblclick");  //perform double-click action
            clicks = 0;             //after action performed, reset counter
        }
    
  },
  dblclick:function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    
  }
};

var $btn = $("#btn");
bindEvent($btn,events,"mydata",$btn);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">MYBtn</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var eventBinder = function(obj, events) {
  $.each(events, function(key, value) {
    obj.on(key, function(e) {
      events[key]();
    });
  });
}

var eventsData = {
  click: function(e) {
    console.log("click");
  },
  dblclick: function(e) {
    console.log("dblclick");
  }
};

eventBinder($("#btn"), eventsData);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">MYBtn</button>
```

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the exact answer, but I tried:

```
var bindEvent = function(dom,events,data,_this){
    dom.bind(events,function(){
    for(var key in events){
      events[key].apply(_this,[data]);
    }
  });
}
```